# Javascript: can't get radio value, it's always return null

Tags: javascript

I'm having problem with getting radio button value. I search thru and follow instruction of the same issues in stackoverflow but doesn't help.  I'd appreciate it if you can help:

The radio_value in the code below always return null.

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Template</TITLE>
  <script>
  function payment_validation(){ 
  var radio_value="";
  var radios=document.getElementsByName("payment");
  for (var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
  if(radios[i].checked){ 
  radio_value=radios[i].value;
  return radio_value;
  break;
  }
  }
  if(radio_value!=""){
  document.getElementById("payment_error").innerHTML="";
  return true; 
  }
  else{
        document.getElementById("payment_error").innerHTML="Please select radio";
  return false; 
  }
  } 
  </script>
 </HEAD>
 
 <BODY> 
  <p>
  Payment Options: 
        <input type="radio" name="payment" id="CC" value="">CreditCard 
        <input type="radio" name="payment" id="DC" value="">DebitCard 
        <input type="radio" name="payment" id="PP" value="">Paypal
        <span style=color:red id= payment_error></span> 
  </p>
     
  <p>
  <input type="button" id="submit_id" value="   SUBMIT   " onclick="payment_validation()">
  </p>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You defined the value to be `""`, what are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- You should try to format your JS with tab indentation so it's easier to read.
- You really only need your `payment_validation` function to return true or false; so remove the line `return radio_value`, and instead just `break`.
- Best practice says to comma separate your variable declarations at the top, rather than declaring `var` more than once.
- You have an unclosed `<p>` tag.
- There is no element with the `payment_error` id, so the code generates an error as is.
- Your `<span>` tag is malformed; it is missing quotes around the attribute values and has a space before `payment_error`.

Altogether, now:

HTML:

```
<p>
  Payment Options:
  <input type="radio" name="payment" id="CC" value="CreditCard">CreditCard
  <input type="radio" name="payment" id="DC" value="DebitCard">DebitCard
  <input type="radio" name="payment" id="PP" value="Paypal">Paypal
</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" id="submit_id" value="   SUBMIT   " onclick="payment_validation()">
</p>

<p style="color: red;" id="payment_error"></p>
```

JS:

```
function payment_validation() {
    var radio_value = "",
        radios = document.getElementsByName("payment");

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            radio_value = radios[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (radio_value != "") {
        document.getElementById("payment_error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("payment_error").innerHTML = "Please select radio";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avXGeK

Comment: Thanks for your advice @benjarwar, it WORKS for me now. Will keep your  advice in mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

use .checked instead of .value. That should help and make it not NULL. so itv would be

```
 radio_value=radios[i].checked;
```